# Conv4D in tf.nn.convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried using tf.nn.convolution() for 6D input with 4D filter. 
But tf.nn.convolution() say "ValueError: `input` and `filter` must have rank at least 3 and at most 5".

My question is, Where is this limitation from?
Only the implementation of Tensorflow? or limitation of CUDA/cuDNN?

(python 3.6, tensorflow 1.12)

Comment: I assume that it a tensorflow limitation, since it is also implemented in the tensorflow CPU version if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?q=ValueError%3A+input+and+filter+must+have+rank+at+least+3+and+at+most+5&unscoped_q=ValueError%3A+input+and+filter+must+have+rank+at+least+3+and+at+most+5)

Comment: I have read more details in the codes. They have a lot of codes about ``channels_first`` and ``channels_last``, which makes it difficult to handle the arbitrary dimensional inputs.

Comment: Do you really need so many dimensions? Can you not reduce the dimensionality before you feed it into the network?If you elaborate more about your use case we might come up with some ideas.

Comment: Actually, I don't know whether it is better to use Conv4D or not. I am now treating an image-style data but each pixel has a 2D feature vector.
Now I am feeding the data to the network in a per-pixel manner (Conv2D). But mathematically, there is no limitation for the dimension of convolution. So I would like to test the Conv4D.

And I want to know how difficult it is to implement.